# SQL query to update table columns where input parameters are not Null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has the below columns.

```
Ticket_id (Primary key, Int)
Attachment1 (varchar)
Attachment2 (varchar)
Attachment3 (varchar)
Attachment4 (varchar)
Attachment5 (varchar)
```

I am writing a stored proc to update this table. there are 6 input parameters for the above 6 columns.

```
@Attached_File1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File2 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File3 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File4 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File5 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Ticket_ID BIGINT
```

I want to write a sql query which will update the table with the values specified in the input parameters. BUT I must not overrite the attachment columns with null. I mean I need to use only those parameters which contains data.

For example, if the table ha a row [10, "aaa", "bbb", null, null, null] and the input parameters are (10, null, null, "ccc", "ddd", null) then after the update the row will become [10, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", null]

How to check for null/empty strings and generate the update query accordingly to achieve this?

Comment: If this is SQL Server then the "plsql" tag is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have to be concerned with a non-null input parameter for a column that is already non-null? If so, what's the remedy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ISNULL

```
UPDATE table_name SET
  Attachment1 = ISNULL(Attachment1, @Attached_File1),
  Attachment2 = ISNULL(Attachment2, @Attached_File2),
  Attachment3 = ISNULL(Attachment3, @Attached_File3),
  Attachment4 = ISNULL(Attachment4, @Attached_File4),
  Attachment5 = ISNULL(Attachment5, @Attached_File5)
WHERE Ticket_id = @Ticket_ID
```

This solution does not overwrite an existing value with a new. If you want to do that, you should switch the values around:

```
ISNULL(@Attached_File1, Attachment1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
update MY_TABLE set Attached_File1 = ISNULL(@parameter1, Attached_File1);
```

Comment: Doesn't sql-server uses `@` rather than `:` for parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply;

```
SET 
   AttachmentX = ISNULL(AttachmentX, @Attached_FileX)
```

or if the params can be empty strings

```
   AttachmentX = ISNULL(AttachmentX, NULLIF(@Attached_FileX, ''))
```

Comment: Isn't that the wrong way around?  OP wants to prevent NULL parameters being written...

Answer (score 1):

In your `UPDATE` statement you could use the `COALESCE` statement, example:

```
SET Attachment1 = COALESCE(@Attached_File1, Attachment1)
```

If `@Attached_File1` is `NULL` then the current value of `Attachment1` will effectively remain unchanged.

Comment: I stand by this answer, there is no reason this should not work - please recheck your code and note that unlike with `ISNULL` the parameters are in the opposite order `COALESCE(@Attached_File1, Attachment1)` and NOT `COALESCE(Attachment1, @Attached_File1)` so you cannot just do a find/replace of `ISNULL` with `COALESCE`.